# Cordova geolocation watchPosition frequency is higher than the options allow it

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, geolocation

in my ionic/angularjs application I'm using the geolocation plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Like in the documentation I use this to configure the watch:

```
var watchOptions = {
    frequency : 10*1000,
    timeout : 60*60*1000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true // may cause errors if true
};

watch = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(on_success,on_error,watchOptions);
```

But however on android the frequency is much higher than 10 seconds (about 0.5 Seconds). On iOS it works great. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Updated in light of comments below**

There is no `frequency` parameter available in the [geolocation options](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#geolocationoptions) for `watchPosition()` hence any value you pass will be ignored. The success callback registered via `watchPosition()` is invoked each time the native location manager receives a position update from the GPS hardware (in the case of `enableHighAccuracy=true`) so it's not called on a fixed interval.

The native location managers (both Android and iOS) are event-driven, i.e. they receive updates from the GPS hardware as and when it delivers them at a non-fixed interval. Hence trying to apply a fixed frequency to this is trying to fit a square peg in a round hole - you cannot demand that the GPS hardware deliver you a location update exactly ever N seconds.

While you can call `getCurrentPosition()` on a fixed interval, this method simply returns last received position or requests a new one.

If the problem is that the updates are too frequent, you could log the time each update is received at, and only accept the next update after N seconds, e.g.

```
var lastUpdateTime,
minFrequency = 10*1000,
watchOptions = {
    timeout : 60*60*1000,
    maxAge: 0,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};

function on_success(position){
    var now = new Date();
    if(lastUpdateTime && now.getTime() - lastUpdateTime.getTime() < minFrequency){
        console.log("Ignoring position update");
        return;
    }
    lastUpdateTime = now;

    // do something with position
}
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(on_success,on_error,watchOptions);
```

This, however, will not stop the device requesting updates more frequently, hence consuming a relatively large amount of battery.

The native Android [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) does allow you to specify a minimum time between updates when requesting location in order to minimise battery drain, however [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) on Android doesn't implement use LocationManager directly, but instead uses the [W3C Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) in the native webview, which does not allow you to specify this.

However, you can use this plugin to do this: [cordova-plugin-locationservices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-locationservices)

It will allow you to specify:

> interval: Set the desired interval for active location updates, in milliseconds.
>
> fastInterval: Explicitly set the fastest interval for location updates, in milliseconds.

Comment: Is there a counterpart for `cordova-plugin-locationservices` for iOS? A workaround I can think of is to create your own wrapper around the default `watchPosition` where you call the `watchPosition` and `clearWatch` depending on the `frequency` value you give it.

Comment: Thanks! However, in your sample code, I think one line is incorrect and should instead be:   if(lastUpdateTime && now.getTime() - lastUpdateTime.getTime() < minFrequency){